# Sequelize: "Model has not been defined" when relationship across multiple databases

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to instanciate one sequelize per Database. Some tables in DB1 has relationships with tables in DB2, and reverse. One of the relationships is DB1.Utilisateur.contenuProvenance_id => DB2.Contenu.id and DB2.Contenu.utilisateur_id => DB1.Utilisateur.id.

Here is the Utilisateur model:

```
@Table
export default class Utilisateur extends Model<Utilisateur> {

    @API() @PrimaryKey @AutoIncrement @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER })
    public id!: number;

    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
    public email!: string;

    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
    public nom!: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => Utilisateur)
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, allowNull: true })
    public parrain_id?: number;

    @ForeignKey(() => Contenu)
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, allowNull: true })
    public contenuProvenance_id?: number;
}
```

(Yes i'm using sequelize-typescript to declare my models as Typescript classes)

And here is how my Sequelize instance are created:

```
let DBs = {};
for (const ZONE of zones)
    DBs[ ZONE.name ] = new Sequelize(ZONE.serveur.bdd.nom, ZONE.serveur.bdd.login, ZONE.serveur.bdd.mdp, {
        host: ZONE.serveur.bdd.hote,
        dialect: "mariadb",
        ...
        models: ZONE.modeles // Array of models
    });
```

The problem: when the first instance (DB1) is created, sequelize don't find the Content table and gives me this error:

```
Error: Contenu has not been defined
    at Sequelize.model (project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:443:13)
    at Sequelize.model (project/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:29:26)
    at project/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:51:46
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at project/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:49:26
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Sequelize.associateModels (project/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:45:16)
    at Sequelize.addModels (project/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:37:14)
    at new Sequelize (project/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:19:22)
```

Is it possible to create the sequelize instances one by one, although there are relations between databases ?

Should I add models after all sequelize instances has been created ?

Thanks for your help guys

Related:

- [SequelizeJS: How to include association (join) across multiple databases without using raw query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722586/sequelizejs-how-to-include-association-join-across-multiple-databases-without)

Comment: Hi, I'm having the exact same problem, were you able to solve it?

Comment: Hi, because Sequelize did not meet my needs in many ways, I ended up by writting my own orm.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you define the entity on  sequlize  object.

```
export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'SEQUELIZE',
    useFactory: async () => {
      const sequelize = new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: ------,
        username: '-----',
        password: '----',
        database: '----',
      });
      sequelize.addModels([Contenu, OtherEntityHere]);
      await sequelize.sync( {alter: true});
      return sequelize;
    },
  },
];
```

or else sequlize wont know the entity and its telling you that its not defined too.

Answer (score -1):

Sequalize doesn't support multiple migration folders or distinguish between the methods you set for individual models. You have to be really specific. I can't tell if you are from what you've provided.

See if this SO question helps: [Migrations in Sequelize in my own folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54404302/5329073)
You have to configure a way around the default path.

This may offer some insight, too: https://medium.com/unetiq/using-multiple-databases-with-nodejs-and-sequelize-59e0abcbbe6f

You can read about it Sequalize's specifics on migration here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#the-sequelizerc-file